# Should I always validate JSON payload against schema?

Tags: java, json, rest, schema

Is there a guideline, best practice or rule of thumb for if and when to validate incoming JSON payload against its schema?
If it is always done, how do I handle minor schema change - should I regenerate POJOs and deploy again?
Is it alright to *never* validate the payload against its schema?

Comment: I think [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) handles this for you.

Comment: It depends on your use case. But, it is always good to validate the json so ensure the input payload is as expected. Validation gives you a better way to ascertain the data is proper. Or else you end up doing the same in the if else blocks.